# Using Density Correction Factors for Fans and Blowers

Tags: design, pressure, pneumatic

I've been researching fans/blowers and their use in pneumatic systems (particularly conveying systems), and I'm confused by the application of density correction factors. Let me describe a sample situation:

I have a wood processing plant in which I will be using a centrifugal fan to move material through a pneumatic system. My pneumatic system is characterized by the system curve $$P_s = K_{sys} Q^2$$
where Q is the volumetric flow (CFM) and $P_s$ is the static pressure. In order to move the material through my system, I need a minimum CFM of (say) 10,000. Via my system curve, I find that this corresponds to a static pressure of (say) 7 inWC.

So, I need a fan that can supply 10,000 CFM at 7 inWC. I will do this by superimposing my system curve on the fan curves for the various fans I might select to determine the HP and RMP requirements. Here is where the density correction comes in:

**My Understanding:**
Ultimately, what I want is material to be moved through my system. The fan gives energy (i.e. *does work*) to the air, and the air in turn gives energy to the material it moves. At a given volumetric flow rate, denser air will have more energy and thus be able to do more work. Now, the 10,000 CFM I need is the flow rate needed under *actual* conditions (ACFM). Fan curves are calculated at standard conditions, so I should convert my ACFM to SCFM before comparing to the charts. I do this by simply multiplying by the standard/actual air density ratio.

**My Question**

1. Do I also need to correct static pressure? Physically speaking, I don't think the pressure generated by the fan is a function of the air density. Particularly because this pressure is just measured relative to ambient air pressure.
2. Is it wrong of me to correct flow rate? Some pages I found online said that CFM should not be adjusted, as centrifugal fans are "constant volume devices" (volumetric flow at a particular RPM does not depend on air density). However, I believe that this reasoning neglects the work/energy considerations I made above.

Any references to pages/papers explaining the underlying physics would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is "WC" a typo for "WG", i.e. "Water gauge"?

Comment: "Water column"; just a different name for the same unit.